# How to load CSV data from a local directory into Memgraph?

Tags: csv, graph-databases, depth-first-search, memgraphdb

How to load CSV data from a local directory into Memgraph and then run the DFS algorithm using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the `LOAD CSV` Cypher clause in order to load the dataset. Here is a link to a simple guide that demonstrates how to load a CSV file step-by-step: https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/import-data/load-csv-clause

DFS:
Did you try relationship traversals without specifying BFS as the method? This should result in a DFS traversal of the nodes and relationships. You can also specify the depth using the parameters `minHops`and `maxHops`:

```
MATCH ({name: 'United Kingdom'})<-[:LIVING_IN*1..2]-(n)
RETURN n;
```

Here is a link to the documentation if you want a more detailed explanation: https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/clauses/match#3-matching-with-variable-length-relationships